# How to adjust vertical and horizontal proportion of QWidget in QSplitter at the time of window initialization?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to make a beautiful layout but fail in initializing QWidget in QSplitter layout. Below is my code:

```
import sys,os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class singleGenePanel(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        lable = QLabel("Retrive information of the Gene: ")
        self.geneName = QLineEdit()
        self.geneName.setPlaceholderText("ENSG00000139618")
        runBtn = QPushButton('Search >')
        runBtn.setStyleSheet("font-size: 20px ;font-weight:bold")
        self.snpsTable = QTableWidget()
        self.keggTable = QTableWidget()
        self.keggTable.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.keggFig = QLabel(alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

        
        inputLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        inputLayout.addWidget(lable)
        inputLayout.addWidget(self.geneName)
        inputLayout.addWidget(runBtn)

        keggSplitter = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        keggSplitter.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        keggSplitter.addWidget(self.keggTable)
        keggSplitter.addWidget(self.keggFig)
        keggSplitter.setStretchFactor(0, 1)
        keggSplitter.setStretchFactor(1, 9)
        keggSplitter.setStyleSheet("QSplitter::handle{background-color: gray; width:5px; border:1px dotted gray}")

        splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)
        splitter.addWidget(self.snpsTable)
        splitter.addWidget(keggSplitter)


        
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(inputLayout)
        layout.addWidget(splitter)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = singleGenePanel()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Why keggSplitter.setStretchFactor(0, 1) and keggSplitter.setStretchFactor(1, 9) don't work, and the porpotion of length of left keggTable and right keggFig is not 1 to 9?

Here is what I want :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QSplitter` uses sophisticated calculations to estimate the sizes that it assigns to each of its child widgets. Important aspects it takes into account are widget size hints.

Try setting

```
self.keggFig.setMinimumWidth(90)
```

and everything will become as you want.

```
import sys,os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class singleGenePanel(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        lable = QLabel("Retrive information of the Gene: ")
        self.geneName = QLineEdit()
        self.geneName.setPlaceholderText("ENSG00000139618")
        runBtn = QPushButton('Search >')
        runBtn.setStyleSheet("font-size: 20px ;font-weight:bold")
        self.snpsTable = QTableWidget()
        
        self.keggTable = QTableWidget() 
        self.keggTable.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.keggFig = QLabel(alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)  
        self.keggFig.setMinimumWidth(90)                          # +
        
        inputLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        inputLayout.addWidget(lable)
        inputLayout.addWidget(self.geneName)
        inputLayout.addWidget(runBtn)

        keggSplitter = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        keggSplitter.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        keggSplitter.addWidget(self.keggTable)
        keggSplitter.addWidget(self.keggFig)
        keggSplitter.setStretchFactor(0, 1)
        keggSplitter.setStretchFactor(1, 9)
        keggSplitter.setStyleSheet(            
            "QSplitter::handle{background-color: gray; width: 5px; border: 1px dotted gray}"
        )

        splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)
        splitter.addWidget(self.snpsTable)
        splitter.addWidget(keggSplitter)
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(inputLayout)
        layout.addWidget(splitter)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = singleGenePanel()
    demo.resize(620, 480)     # +
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. By the way, how do you determine the number of 90? Is there any guideline, or just depending on experience?